# android textview toggle single line to multi line on click

Tags: android, android-view, textview

I'm trying to make a textview with two states. 
In the normal state, the textview should show a single line or height should be equal to that of a single line. 
In the toggled state, it's height should be the height of all lines or it should show all lines in the textview. 
The textview should toggle on click.

And I want to know if this will work in a ListAdapter.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't [textView.setSingleLine(boolean singleLine)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine%28boolean%29) work?

Comment: You try it out and tell me :)

Comment: tried it out and it works:-P
But when I set single line to true, at the end of the line, half a character is shown if the text is long. Any way to make it disappear?

Comment: TextView's setEllipsize() will add '...' where ever you want if the text is too long. you can select TextUtils.TruncateAt.END.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt)